# Google Spreadsheet time-driven event doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My task is to check Spreadsheet cell data and if it = "WARNING"(for example) send mail notifications.

Explanation:

1. Check the data in spreadsheet cell and if it not equival to "WARNING":

   ```
                   - set status for cell "first"
   ```
2. Check the data in spreadsheet cell and if it equival to "WARNING" and status "first":

   ```
                   - send email

                   - msgBox - "WARNING first"

                   - set status for cell "second"
   ```
3. When next time script runing and cell value = "WARNING", cell status "second":

   ```
                    - just msgBox - "WARNING second"
   ```
4. and so on, if value changed to nonWARNING  - set status for cell "first"

My script

```
  function AlertMe() {
  var status = ScriptProperties.getProperty('AlertStatus')+"";
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("fdata").getRange( "E2").getCell(1, 1).getValue().toString();
  if (value.match("WARNING" )&&status.match("first")) { 
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('AlertStatus', 'second');
    Browser.msgBox(value+' '+status);
    MailApp.sendEmail("mail@gmail.com, mail2@gmail.com", "Alert from my spreadsheet", "Parameter: " + value);
  }
  else { 
    if (!value.match("WARNING")) 
    ScriptProperties.setProperty('AlertStatus', 'first')
    else { 
    if (status.match("second")) 
    Browser.msgBox(value+' '+status);
  }
  }
```

}

its work correct only if I run script manually or set trigger On open or On change event.

**My question:
How to execute script with the Time-Driven trigger when i log off from Google Docs?**

I try to use something like that, but it dosnt work correct

```
var DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID = "0AprqtrrrraFdGxDdXFlMjM4Z0rFwerrrU9PcFlWMVE"; 
var value = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName("fdata").getRange( "E2").getCell(1, 1).getValue().toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Browser.msgBox()` function is not available when a function is executed under a time driven trigger. Try removing these from your function.